# i am unable to use malloc and free using stdio.h library

Tags: c

I have the following issue/question:
I'm currently working on visual studio in C
I made a program that uses the functions `malloc` and free, I am sure I used them well, but when I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
Error C3861 'free': identifier not found
Error (active)  identifier "free" is undefined  
(same errors for malloc)
```

the only include statement I made was for `stdio.h` (which I usually add and it works fine for these functions)

I added `stdlib` and the problem was resolved, but when I serve this chore I may be downgraded for including a library we did not work with so far, can anyone tell me why the functions don't work with just `stdio.h`?

Comment: Please paste your code as we can inspect it. And it is C language, not c#. Please remove c# tag.

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:c#]? Also, please enclose a [MCVE] to demonstrate what you have tried so far.

Comment: hey sorry i added c# by mistake, should i paste all of my code? because its 300 lines

Answer (score 3):

`<stdlib.h>` is the correct header to include when calling `malloc` and `free`.  In fact, it's correct to say that you *must* include `<stdlib.h>` (directly or indirectly) when calling `malloc` and `free`.

There are lots of reasons why it might have worked for you once before even though you didn't.  Without seeing that older code, I couldn't say why.  Don't worry about it.  Just always include `<stdlib.h>` when calling `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Malloc and free is defined under stdlib.h. So without including it your program wont work.

Comment: OP stated "i added stdlib and the problem was resolved"

Comment: but i have used them in the past while only including stdio.h, has something changed since?

Comment: How exactly have you used it in the past? Some IDE's pre include elementary libraries. Maybe thats why it worked in the past.

Comment: well in the past i used it just as now, i did recieve warnings about free and malloc but the program compiled, i realise it would be better to add stdlib in such case but we are not allowed to

Comment: Did you change IDE?

Comment: i have always worked on same filetype in visual studio(.c files in c)

Comment: I do not agree with "without including it your program wont work". It will work, as the functions will be found in the library when linking. There will be compilation warnings though.

Comment: yes i thought the same should happen, but it just doesent compile